# Enabling layer-backed views?

Tags: calayer

I keep seeing that in order to get transformations around the center point of a CALayer, you need to turn on layer-backing? I can't figure out how to do it though! Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised you didn't see that in the docs. Just send the layer the wantsLayer message. Or if you prefer dot syntax just do `layer.wantsLayer = YES;`